# Text bug on specific text, with Unity3D, on specific device (Android Samsung S4 Mini)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, text-rendering

We're hitting a wall at the moment, trying to get a full release of our game and one of the things that's catching us just at the minute is a weird issue where we see blocks instead of text on an area,

[image: blocky text]

What it's supposed to look like, "YOU" "RIVAL",

[image: nice text]

We're only experiencing it after on second entrance to the scene shown, but I have seen the issue occur before, on another app, Reddit is Fun (Android only),

[image: Reddit is Fun]

No idea what's happening, doesn't happen on other devices, OSs, or in the Editor and nothing's showing up in the logs, but without being able to pinpoint it, it's a bit of a blocker to us releasing.

Comment: Looks to me like the font your game is using is not installed on that specific device. Did you try to change the font?

Comment: And in a typical fashion, 5 minutes after posting, we got the answer. The text animates, and if it ever starts with, or goes to a Z scale of 0, that happens, so changing min to 0.001 instead fixed it.

Comment: Cool! I am happy for you. You should answer your own question and mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so this is a weird one.  The text goes all wrong if the `z` scale of the text ever gets set to `0`, and changed from that point.

This text was animated, just scaled down to invisible after the first entrance to the scene, so if we restarted the race, the text had been scaled back to it's normal size, but because it *had* been `0`, it was obviously wrong.

So, two ways to get around it, first choose *not* exactly `0`, choose `0.001` or something, and then hide it prevents this from happening, or because it's a 2D object, you can choose to just scale down the `x` and `y` scale, but not the `z`.